# get contextPath in freemarker template to link other servlets

Tags: java, servlets, hyperlink, freemarker

WElcome. I am creating web aplication ,stack of : servlets, freemarker as view layer.I am trying to do that in accordance with MVC pattern. I want to include to all my pages common page fragment ala menu which contain  hyperlinks to others servelts/pages. One menu included to all pages.
I have to add that some of my servlets are mapped in other subdirectiories example:

user/editProfile
admin/statistics
admin/privileges
index
lastMessages

And like I said before i want to make one common menu page which be included to others page. When hiperlinks work fine in template rendered by servlet mapped at "index" but already from admin/statistics no. I think i can use contextPath to create path to others websites but i can't do this in freemarker;/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely can do that in FreeMarker, but don't. Surely FreeMarker doesn't contain such feature out-of-the-box. A fundamental difference from JSP is exactly that FreeMarker doesn't dictate anything (not even that you are using it with Servlet-s), so the framework author has full control over what the template authors will see and how. If you want to expose such functionality, do it through the data-model, or through a shared variable (see `Configuration.setSharedVariable`), or through an `#import`-ed FTL that calls out into the Java API of the framework (Spring does that AFAIR). From the template-author's perspective usually there's a single variable that holds all the web-framework functionality, let's say, `fw`, and then you do stuff like `${fw.url('admin/statistics')}`, which the framework will expand to an absolute URL. Note in the example that the template author doesn't have to deal with highly technical details like inserting the servlet context URL. Also this way the target can just be some Action identifier, and then you can have another layer of configuration that maps URL-s to Actions (this flexibility is useful for SEO for example), which also means that you can spot broken links automatically.

Answer (score 1):

for those learning and still struggling, as I did, I want to share with you and complement @ddekany's answer, one could do, in the servlet:

```
public class FW {
    String contextPath0;
    String contextPath;
    FW(HttpServletRequest request) {
        contextPath0 = request.getContextPath();
        contextPath = contextPath0 + "/";
    }
    public String getContextPath() {
        return contextPath0;
    }
    public String url(String path) {
        if (path.startsWith("/")) return contextPath0 + path;
        return contextPath + path;
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("fw", new FW(request));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/template-00.ftl").forward(request, response);
}
```

and later, in .ftl template

```
<pre style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;">
fw.context path: "${fw.contextPath}"
fw.url 1: "${fw.url('/my/safe/absolute/path')}"
fw.url 2: "${fw.url('my/safe/relative/path')}"
</pre>
```